# Каковы отличия между fstream::fail() и fstream::bad()?

Tags: c++, fstream

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем отличаются:

```
fstream::fail()
fstream::bad()
```

Я перерыл кучу документации и обсуждений, но так ничего и не понял.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/
vs. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/bad/

Comment: @asianirish, большое спасибо, но я это уже прочитал, несколько раз. Ясности это не внесло. Например, у меня есть текстовый файл. В какой-то момент я пытаюсь считать из файла число, но в файле больше нет чисел, там есть только перевод строки. Так вот, оператор `<<` считывает в число мусор и выставляет `badbit`, но не `failbit`. Это какое-то безумие. Почему провалившаяся операция выставляет `badbit`, но не `failbit`?

Comment: [лучше смотреть на cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) *"Например ..."* - приводите [mcve] or it did not happen

Comment: перевод строки игнорируется, дальше если ничего нет, то получается попытка чтения за концом файла, а это ломает поток и выставляется  badbit, т.е. вы уже не можете командой clear() исправить ситуацию и делать что то другое(это и есть принципиальное отличие). Но лучше не будем гадать и послушаемся совету  в комментарии выше

Answer (score 0):

`bad()` - все совсем плохо физически и не исправить (невозможно прочесть, закончился файл, сбойный сектор), а `fail()` - плохо логически (ну там не тот формат, например).